# Graphql in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, graphql, parameter-passing

I am using graphql in jmeter for API testing. Where in graphal we have the query and variable section.
My query would require a client ID which is int. Where as in Variable if I try to pass "{clientid : ${clientid}}"(here I am passing the CSV config variable, for testing the app for multiple users). But it is throwing an error like $ is unauthorised and expecting a (json,null,true or false).

Please help me out how I can pass the clientid which is a csv config variable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add a Debug Sampler and check if the `clientid` value is available in the response data tab? What is the value of the `clientid`  in the request?  You can find this information in the View result Tree--> Request tab

Comment: The value of a client ID in request is an integer value.

Comment: We can convert a string value into an int value. BTW what's in your request? Looks like it's not getting resolved.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your CSV Data Set Config setup is not very correct so the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) placeholder isn't getting substituted with its respective value from the CSV file.

We cannot help without seeing first couple of lines of the CSV file and your CSV Data Set Config setup so far I can only suggest re-visit the configuration and cross-check it with [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

You can observe JMeter Properties and Variables with their values using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script), if you don't see `clientid` line there - the variable is not set and JMeter sends it as it is, to wit `"{clientid : ${clientid}}"` and doesn't substitute `${clientid}` with the value from CSV

Comment: My CSV file is in notepad which has integer value, I have added the sampler as well to check what value is being picked up. It's fetching correctly, but in graphql it's not getting replaced